# Count number of files and save them in an HTML file

Tags: shell

I have a lot of movies (with pictures over 15,000 files in one folder) in my synology-diskstation and I think the fastest way is to count the number of files an simple shell script - the problem is I have also some movie trailers.

All movies have the file extension `.mp4`, some files have a trailer file and all files have the genre in their filename.

Example of filename syntax - ever the same:

```
Moviename (Action) (2011) HD Trailer.mp4
Moviename (Action) (2011) HD.mp4
Moviename2 (Drama) (2015) HD Trailer.mp4
Moviename2 (Drama) (2015) HD.mp4
Moviename3 (Horror) (2012) HD Trailer.mp4
Moviename3 (Horror) (2012) HD.mp4
```

1. I need an command to get the result of all movies without the trailers - per genre.
2. How can I generate an simple HTML table file?

My Ideas - not tested:

```
CountActionTrailer="`ls /some/path/noviedir/ | grep '(Action)*Trailer.mp4' | wc -l`"
CountActionMovies="`ls /some/path/noviedir/ | grep '(Action)*.mp4' | wc -l`"
CountActionRealcount=$((CountActionMovies-CountActionTrailer))
```

Any ideas or better ideas for question 1 and 2 with a code example?

Comment: Need directly shell? I think you could use JS to do that and matching with a regex p should be lot easier.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) you could just `| grep -v 'Trailer.mp4'` to filter or include only (without `-v`) the trailers. Also `*` doesn't work in grep they you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty script to do what you want:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#
GENRES="Action Drama Horror"

for G in ${GENRES}
do

    COUNT=$(ls | grep "($G)" | sed -e 's/ Trailer//' | uniq | wc -l)
    echo ${G} - ${COUNT}
done
```

Here's an example run:

```
12:09pm> ls
Moviename (Action) (2011) HD Trailer.mp4 
Moviename (Action) (2011) HD.mp4 
Moviename2 (Drama) (2015) HD Trailer.mp4 
Moviename3 (Horror) (2012) HD Trailer.mp4 
Moviename3 (Horror) (2012) HD.mp4 
Moviename4 (Horror) (2012) HD.mp4 
12:10pm> /tmp/quick.sh
Action - 1
Drama - 1
Horror - 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this script

```
#!/bin/sh

GENRES="Action Drama Comedy"

TABLE='<table><tr><th>Genre</th><th>Count</th></tr>'
for G in ${GENRES};do
        COUNT=`ls | grep "($G)" | grep -v Trailer | wc -l)`
        echo "GENRE:$G COUNT:$COUNT"
    TABLE=$TABLE"<tr><td>$G</td><td>$COUNT</td></tr>"
done
TABLE=$TABLE"</table>"
echo $TABLE
```

If you wish your HTML table to be saved on a file, just put

```
echo $TABLE > filename.html
```

at the end of your script.